# Knowing 3 points of a figure, the fourth point can take how many values so that the given figure form a parallelogram. (GRE exam 9768 Q.42)

Tags: geometry, gre-exam

> [image]

I do not know how to solve it, could anyone give me a hint? or tell me if this question [How to test whether a set of four points can form a parallelogram](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891803/how-to-test-whether-a-set-of-four-points-can-form-a-parallelogram) is useful in the solution or irrelevant?

Comment: have you made a Picture? there are three cases

Comment: Ok .... thank you for the hint @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I will make it.

Comment: it is $ABCD,ABDC,ADBC$

Comment: How ? why? I do not understand u @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: A parallelogram is an **affine** concept so you can without loss of generality look at an equilateral triangle. Draw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment. The three given points form a $V$ of bottom $C$. The three cases are : 1) placing $D$ so $CA$ is diagonal  $CB$ a side.
2) versa 1)

3) $CA$ and $CB$ are two sides.